# app getting resized

Tags: android, android-image

I created an alarm app. I gave the images in mdpi, ldpi and hdpi. But when I tested my app in an motorola phone . I was getting my app to cover only some part of the screen and rest was blank. I was as if my app was resized to occupy only a portion of the screen and rest was blank. It was testes fine in may other phones. Can any one suggest a solution pls .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Never mind thanks I fixed it .

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because your images does not fit to the screen size.Use [ninepatch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)([ref](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable.html)) images for your images.This allows your application to adjust the images to fit to your required size.

Answer (score 0):

have you hardcoded layout sizes ?  fill parent values for layout width and height.